# Read file and remove \n and spaces from lines

Tags: python, file

I have a file named numbers.txt and this is the content:

```
1
2
3
4
```

This is the code I used to read the lines in numbers.txt:

```
with open("numbers.txt") as numbers:
    for number in numbers:
        try:
            print(number + ' is a number!')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Output:

```
1
 is a number!
2
 is a number!
3
 is a number!
4 is a number!
```

I wanted it to output this:

```
1 is a number!
2 is a number!
3 is a number!
4 is a number!
```

How can I get this output?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strip` function to get rid of `\n` char at the end of the lines.

```py
with open("numbers.txt") as numbers:
    for number in numbers:
        try:
            print(number.strip() + ' is a number!')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Produces following output

```
1 is a number!
2 is a number!
3 is a number!
4 is a number!
```