# How to print lines from a file wrapped in double quotes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print lines from a text file to look like this format:

```
"line one",
"line two",
"line three",
```

I'm using this code

```
file1 = open('notes.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print('"'+line+'",')
```

but it ends up looking like this instead:

```
"line one
",
"line two
",
"line three",
```

Is there a way so that it isn't just the last line that has its closing quotation mark on the same line? I'm using `print` to format instead of printing the lines directly because I want the double quotation marks per item per line.

Comment: Use the `end` argument of `print`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: @RandomDavis No, this is not the problem here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file and remove \n and spaces from lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68272031/read-file-and-remove-n-and-spaces-from-lines)

Comment: The title and the question is misleading, as it's not about printing and not about the double-quotes, but about stripping the newline character when reading lines from a file, which is addressed by [Read file and remove \n and spaces from lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68272031/read-file-and-remove-n-and-spaces-from-lines) or the more canonical duplicate [How to read a file without newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12330522/2745495)

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this is because the file you're reading from contains \n at the end of each line. Use `rstrip()` to remove it.

```py
file1 = open('notes.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print('"'+line.rstrip()+'",')
```

Comment: Or with an f-string: `print(f'"{line.rstrip()}",')`.

Answer (score 1):

The `readlines` command doesn't remove the newline character at the end of each line. One approach is to instead do

```
file1 = open('notes.txt', 'r')
lines = file1.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the rstrip()**

The rstrip method returns a new string with trailing whitespace removed, whitespace includes the hidden '\n' at the very end of each line, which indicates the end of the line. Therefore, here is the solution.

```
    file1 = open('notes.txt', 'r')
    lines = file1.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print('"' + line.rstrip() + '",')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating over file with `file1.readlines()`, it adds `'\n'` at the end of the line.

Try this code:

```
lines = file1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print('"'+line.replace('\n', '')+'",')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('notes.txt', 'r')
lines = file.read().split('\n')
for line in lines:
    print(f'"{line}",')
```